# How much time does it takes for Noctilucous Jade to reappear?

Tags: genshin-impact

How much time does it takes for Noctilucous Jade to reappear after you pick it up in the world? I need it for Beidou and Yanfei.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Noctilucous Jade like most local specialty items respaw on a two days timer.

Since you asked, it is also worth noticing that the official online maps shows a concentration of Jade in the Mingyun Village area.

[image]